# How do I make the bashls language server work with nvim-lspconfig?

Tags: neovim, lsp, bash, lazyvim

bashls is not working. I have multiple working servers with nvim-lspconfig yet I
can't figure out how to make the bashls server work at any capacity.

I've tried this

```
            ... other lsps ...
            rust_analyzer = {},
            dockerls = {},
            bashls = {
               cmd = { "bash-language-server", "start" },
               filetypes = { "sh", "bash" }
            },
            tsserver = {},
            volar = {},
            lemminx = {},

            ... other lsps ...
```

and also with only

```
bashls = {},
```

I already ran

```
pnpm i -g bash-language-server
```

and restarted the machine, too.

I'm not aware of any other required configuration. I've so far done the same
process I follow for any language server, but this one refuses to work. Any
ideas? I am using lazy/lazy.nvim for package management.

Here is my full lspconfig plugin configuration

```
return {
'neovim/nvim-lspconfig',
event = { 'BufReadPre', 'BufNewFile' },
dependencies = {
    { 'williamboman/mason.nvim', opts = {} },
    { 'folke/neodev.nvim',       opts = {} },
    { 'j-hui/fidget.nvim',       opts = {},       tag = 'legacy' },
    { 'folke/neoconf.nvim',      cmd = "Neoconf", config = true },
    'williamboman/mason-lspconfig.nvim',
},
config = function()
    local on_attach = function(_, bufnr)
        local nmap = function(keys, func, desc)
            if desc then
                desc = 'LSP: ' .. desc
            end

            vim.keymap.set('n', keys, func, { buffer = bufnr, desc = desc })
        end
        nmap('<leader>lr', vim.lsp.buf.rename, '[r] Rename')
        nmap('<leader>la', vim.lsp.buf.code_action, '[r] Code Action')
        nmap('<leader>lD', vim.lsp.buf.declaration, '[D] Go to declaration')
        nmap('<leader>ld', vim.lsp.buf.definition, '[d] Go to definition')
        nmap('<leader>lT', vim.lsp.buf.type_definition, '[T] Type definition')
        nmap('<leader>g', require('telescope.builtin').lsp_references, '[g] Go to references')
        nmap('<leader>li', vim.lsp.buf.implementation, '[i] Go to implementation')
        nmap('<leader>ls', require('telescope.builtin').lsp_document_symbols, '[s] Document symbols')
        nmap('<leader>lw', require('telescope.builtin').lsp_dynamic_workspace_symbols, '[w] Workspace symbols')
        nmap('<leader>lh', vim.lsp.buf.hover, '[h] Hover Documentation')
        nmap('<C-k>', vim.lsp.buf.signature_help, 'Signature Documentation')
        vim.api.nvim_buf_create_user_command(bufnr, 'Format', function(_)
            vim.lsp.buf.format()
        end, { desc = 'Format current buffer' })
    end
    local servers = {
        omnisharp = {
            cmd = { "dotnet", "/usr/local/bin/omnisharp/OmniSharp.dll" },
            enable_editorconfig_support = true,
            enable_ms_build_load_projects_on_demand = false,
            enable_roslyn_analyzers = true,
            organize_imports_on_format = true,
            enable_import_completion = false,
            sdk_include_prereleases = true,
            analyze_open_documents_only = false,
        },
        rust_analyzer = {},
        dockerls = {},
        bashls = {
            cmd = { "bash-language-server", "start" },
            filetypes = { "sh", "bash" }
        },
        tsserver = {},
        volar = {},
        lemminx = {},
        html = {},
        jsonls = {},
        cssls = {},
        tailwindcss = {},
        pylsp = {},
        sqlls = {},
        gradle_ls = {},
        kotlin_language_server = {},
        lua_ls = {
            Lua = {
                workspace = { checkThirdParty = false },
                telemetry = { enable = false },
                globals = { 'vim' },
            },
        },
    }
    local capabilities = vim.lsp.protocol.make_client_capabilities()
    capabilities = require('cmp_nvim_lsp').default_capabilities(capabilities)
    local mason_lspconfig = require 'mason-lspconfig'
    mason_lspconfig.setup {
        ensure_installed = vim.tbl_keys(servers),
    }
    mason_lspconfig.setup_handlers {
        function(server_name)
            require('lspconfig')[server_name].setup {
                capabilities = capabilities,
                on_attach = on_attach,
                settings = servers[server_name],
            }
        end,
    }
end
}
```

Comment: [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604) might help narrow down the cause.